# How to resolve a conflict in JetGradle on IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.2?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I am new to the Gradle integration JetGradle in `IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.2` and currently I ran into a conflict with a compile time dependency.

Currently I do not know how to solve this conflict since IDEA does not provide me more informations than this little screenshot. Do you ran into a similar problem and were able to fix it? Any hints are appreciated.

[image: Conflict]

Update: I have found out that IntelliJ IDEA is somehow unable to attach the `joda-time-2.1.jar` to the `joda-time-2.1 library` [image: No-jar].

If I then manually add the JAR the conflict is successfully resolved. Is there a way IntelliJ can tell my why it does not add the JAR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that the library is defined either in gradle or IDE but the jar is not attached to it at the IDE side.

AFAI there is no GUI at the IDE side that helps to resolve this situation. Please create a dedicated feature request at the tracker.

Denis

Comment: Three additional questions. 1.) Why does this happen (bug, error while attaching to IDE)? 2.) Can track this somewhere in a log file? 3.) Where should I put the feature request?